# ASP.NET MVC Model Binding not setting properties of a type that inherits List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ViewModel with a collection property. I wanted that collection type, which was originally a `List<T>` to have some additional properties on it so I created a class that inherits from `List<T>` and defined the properties on it. When I post to my controller action, one of those properties (the only one I'm posting) is not getting set even though the posted name looks correct to me.

The list class:

```
public class ClassEnrollmentPaymentPlanVMList : List<ClassEnrollmentPaymentPlanVM>
{
    public Guid StudentID { get; set; }
    public Guid ClassEventID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid SelectedPricePlanID { get; set; }
}
```

The VM containing the list (omitted extra properties for brevity):

```
public class ClassEnrollmentFormVM
{
    public Guid StudentID { get; set; }

    public Guid ClassEventID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public ClassEnrollmentPaymentPlanVMList AvailablePaymentPlans { get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetClassPaymentPlans(ClassEnrollmentFormVM vm)
    {
        AjaxResponse response = new AjaxResponse();

        ...

        return response.ToContentResult();
    }
```

The AJAX post to GetClassPaymentPlans (Pulled from Chrome dev tools. URL decoded):

```
StudentID: 6267cacc-c5c3-41d8-bd77-65bd8be31b7f
ClassEventID: 20d1d0e3-e6fc-4603-b7cc-8373b3d22527
StartDate: 10/3/2018 12:00:00 AM
EndDate: 5/8/2019 12:00:00 AM
AvailablePaymentPlans[0].PricePlanID: 329f138e-cf9b-427c-b944-75304510caa9
AvailablePaymentPlans[0].ScheduledPayments[0].DueDate: 12/27/2018
AvailablePaymentPlans[1].PricePlanID: c3924757-861f-4456-bde5-782ba2759546
AvailablePaymentPlans[1].ScheduledPayments[0].DueDate: 12/27/2018
AvailablePaymentPlans.SelectedPricePlanID: c3924757-861f-4456-bde5-782ba2759546
AvailablePaymentPlans[2].PricePlanID: 64e622f8-6bec-48c7-96b8-faee3fc17832
AvailablePaymentPlans[2].ScheduledPayments[0].DueDate: 12/27/2018
AvailablePaymentPlans[2].ScheduledPayments[1].DueDate: 1/2/2019
AvailablePaymentPlans[2].ScheduledPayments[2].DueDate: 2/2/2019
AvailablePaymentPlans[2].ScheduledPayments[3].DueDate: 3/5/2019
AvailablePaymentPlans[2].ScheduledPayments[4].DueDate: 4/5/2019
AvailablePaymentPlans[2].ScheduledPayments[5].DueDate: 5/6/2019
```

But `vm.AvailablePaymentPlans.SelectedPricePlanID` is equal to `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` when it hits `GetClassEnrollmentForm`. At first I thought maybe it wasn't posting because the elements are hidden, but you can see above that a `AvailablePaymentPlans.SelectedPricePlanID` key is submitted and I can see in Visual Studio that Request.Form includes that key as well. Does the default binder see that it's a List and ignore the fact that it's a derived type? Interestingly, in the Watch window or when hovering over the vm, Visual Studio also ignores the additional properties on `AvailablePaymentPlans` and does not show them, but intellisense does offer them as if the property were declared on `ClassEnrollmentForm` as the base class `List<ClassEnrollmentPaymentPlanVM>`. This is using .NET Framework 4.6.2

Comment: Why wouldn't you keep it as a good old `List<>` and move the extra properties to `ClassEnrollmentFormVM`?

Comment: Recommended reading:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt

Comment: @Imantas because I don’t want the view to be coupled with a ClassEnrollmentFormVM. I could create a class containing a list and am already considering scrapping this whole structure and starting over, but I need to know why it’s not working regardless.

Comment: I think you need to make a custom model binder for this class.

Comment: @xr280xr in that case you should consider creating another nested VM which *contains* a list. Be sure to read the material that Amy provided a link to. Strongly recommended.

Comment: I read it. A ViewModel represents a "real world" view, which "is" whatever you say it is. So I don't think there's really a strong, fundamental OOP case against the properties being defined on the list, though I do admit the choice was born from convenience and poor planning. In fact, I don't consider ViewModels to be OOP at all. In asp.net MVC, they're usually just fancy data structures. I don't think using a class with a list property, instead, is a bad idea, in fact I think it plays nicer with asp.net MVC all around. It's a good suggestion, but a different topic. Thanks for your feedback.